# Swift and JSON questions

Tags: arrays, json, swift

I'm kind of new to Swift currently playing around with Stickers.

I have a JSON file with the following structure:

```
{
 "stickers": [{
    "filename": "happy_face",
    "description": "Happy Face",
    "premium": "false",
    "categories": ["blue", "green", "red"],
    "genders": ["male", "female"]
 },{
    "filename": "sad_face",
    "description": "Sad Face",
    "premium": "false",
    "categories": ["blue", "green", "red", "yellow"],
    "genders": ["male"]
  }]
}
```

Stickers will have the same filename, but will be separated into folders according to their category and gender.

I can read the JSON data just fine. My problem is when I'm trying to make some use of the JSON data.

My goal is to separate the stickers according to their categories, which could vary depending on the sticker, the user will later be able to switch categories, and the correct stickers will be displayed.

```
let stickerPack = StickerPack.load()
let allStickers = stickerPack!["stickers"] as? [[AnyHashable : Any]]

func getStickersWithCategory(category: String){

var stickers = [AnyObject]()

for sticker in allStickers! {
    let cat = sticker["categories"] as? [String]
    for item in cat! {
        if item.contains(category){
            stickers.append(sticker)
       }
    }
  }
}
```

The result of this is

> "Argument type '[AnyHashable : Any]' does not conform to expected type 'AnyObject'"

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Is it possible with this JSON structure? or is it better to have a different structure, with each category and gender separated? this would lead to a lot of repetition. But maybe I'm creating more problems by trying to keep the JSON structure this way.

All help appreciated!

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsondecoder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be more type specific, this avoids that kind of errors.

This JSON array is `[[String:Any]]` and **never** `AnyHashable` because the keys are required to be string

```
let allStickers = stickerPack!["stickers"] as? [[String:Any]]
```

`stickers` is the same type and **never** something including `AnyObject`. All JSON types are value types (`Any`).

```
var stickers = [[String:Any]]()
```

You can filter the array *swiftier* and it's recommended to safely unwrap all optionals

```
if let stickerPack = StickerPack.load(),
   let allStickers = stickerPack["stickers"] as? [[String:Any]] {
     stickers = allStickers.filter({ (sticker) -> Bool in
         guard let categories = sticker["categories"] as? [String] else { return false }
         return categories.contains(category)
     })
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you declared `allStickers` as `let allStickers = stickerPack!["stickers"] as? [[AnyHashable : Any]]`, which means that its type will be `[[AnyHashable:Any]]?` or `Array<Dictionary<AnyHashable:Any>>`. When you are iterating through that array in `for sticker in allStickers!`, the type of `sticker` will be `Dictionary<AnyHashable:Any>`. `Dictionary` is a struct, so it doesn't conform to `AnyObject`, and hence you cannot add `sticker` to `stickers`, which is declared as an array of `AnyObjects`.

So changing `var stickers = [AnyObject]()` to `var stickers = [Any]()`, or more specifically `var stickers = [[AnyHashable:Any]]()` should solve your issue.

```
func getStickersWithCategory(category: String){
    var stickers = [[AnyHashable:Any]]()

    for sticker in allStickers! {
        let cat = sticker["categories"] as? [String]
        for item in cat! {
            if item.contains(category){
                stickers.append(sticker)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Btw you are encouraged to use `Codable` in Swift 4 when handling JSON.